# stack memory reuse gcc optimization in C?

Tags: c, gcc, reactive-programming, dataflow

I want to implement reactive programming in C. Reactive programming is a form of data-flow programming. So you have pieces of code that send data to the next pieces of code etc.

In the single thread case, that would require that I create a lot of temporary values.

Does gcc have an option to reuse the stack memory of temporary variables that will not be used anymore?

To do that, It requires to analyze the data flow of the program. Which algorithm does it use?
Most importantly, can i rely on it?

The other option is do this myself. Allocate the necessary memory as a char array and then use pointers.

Comment: How much memory are you putting on the stack that you need to reuse some? :P

Comment: You can look at [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion) to understand the problem.

Comment: Still, most macs, by default have a max of 8 mb of stack. Are you recurring that much? :P

Comment: A way to greatly minimize the stack usage is to define a struct that contains all variations of the data.,  malloc that area at the first function to execute.  Then pass the ptr to that malloc'd area to each successive function.

Comment: @user3629249 on the downside you would lose speed here though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your model and envrionment, there might be a "dirty" solution: Frequently, reactive programms calls functions as procedures, i.e., without a return value. In case of C, that corresponds to a `void`  function. If your framework follows this model and gcc, you can use the `noreturn` attribute.

Please note, that it is not forbidden to return from a function marked by `noreturn`. However, no guarantees on local values and return values are made, because the compile may optimize them away. However, this exactly what you want.

To allow void functions only, you may collect the results (reactions) to your events in a global state.

If you want a more general but not automated solution, there is a more comfortable way than your array approach: Simply alloc all non needed variables on the heap and fee them before the next function call.